# How to detect scroll event in InAppWebView in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview

I want to know when the user scrolls the webview so that I can handle some operations. But currently I'm unable to detect the scroll event.

```
InAppWebView(
            onScrollChanged: (controller, int x, int y) => print('Scrolling'),
            key: _key,
            gestureRecognizers: gestureRecognizers,
            initialUrlRequest: viewModel.urlRequest,
          ),
```

And these are the recognizers and key.

```
final UniqueKey _key = UniqueKey();
    final Set<Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>? gestureRecognizers = {
      Factory(() => EagerGestureRecognizer()),
      Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
        () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
      )
    };
```

OnScrollChanged function says in description as below

> NOTE for Web: this event will be called only if the iframe has the same origin.

**I need to detect scroll event in InAppWebView for Flutter web**

And I'm unaware of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `onScrollChanged` and `onOverScrolled` and didn't face any issues with these on detecting the scroll event.
If you have any problems please update the question.